# Are the microprocessors 'encoding format' specific?

Tags: unicode, encoding, format, ascii

A computer system is based on binary system. Data/instructions are encoded in binary. Encoding can be carried out in many formats - ASCII, UNICODE etc.

Is a microprocessor made for a chosen 'encoding format' ? if yes, how would it become compatible to other encoding formats? wouldn't there be a performance penalty in that case?

when we create a program, how its encoding format is chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII and UNICODE are encoding of text data and have nothing about binary data.

Comment: how does the compiler know what encoding format to expect out of the user's code?

Comment: @Saurabh you mean how compiler knows about encoding of source files or what?

Comment: @Saurabh: It doesn't. You have to know the encoding, standardize on it, get it from some higher-level protocol, or even just guess it. A file or a chunk of memory is just a sequence of bytes without inherent properties.

Comment: @andrey yes  how would a compiler knows about encoding of source files?

Comment: @Saurabh there two main encodings ASCII + local (for higher chars) or Unicode of some sort. Unicode one usually start with byte order mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 2):

No, all microprocessors know about is binary numbers - they don't have a clue about the meaning of those numbers. That meaning is provided by us and by our tools used to build programs. For example, if you compile a C++ program using Visual Studio, it will use multi-byte characters, but the CPU doesn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

One area where the microprocessor architecture does matter is [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)—for example, when you try to read a UTF-16LE encoding file on a big-endian machine, you have to swap the individual bytes of each code unit to get the expected 16-bit integer. This is an issue for all encoding forms whose code unit is wider than one byte. See section 2.6 [of the second chapter of the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch02.pdf) for a more in-depth discussion. The processor itself still works with individual integer numbers, but as a library developer, you have to deal with the mapping from files (i.e., byte sequences) to memory arrays (i.e., code unit sequences).

Comment: does it mean that a microprocessor cares only about the instructions and there format, which I presume is fixed? choice of encoding format is only meant for user's non-computational data (characters and symbols)?